# Unfold anonymous function in Coq proof

Tags: coq

I am stuck trying to prove something in Coq that involves the use of a type class.

The specific type class is almost identical to this Functor type class: https://gist.github.com/aztek/2911378

My instance looks like this:

```
Instance ListFunctor : Functor list := { fmap := map }.
  (* Proof stuff here *)
Defined.
```

`map` is the map over lists from the standard library.

The "proof" I am doing is basically just a unit test:

```
Example list_map_test : fmap (fun x => x + 1) (1::2::3::nil) = (2::3::4::nil).
```

My goal looks like this and I am stuck:

```
(let (fmap0, _, _) := ListFunctor in fmap0) nat nat
 (fun x : nat => x + 1) (1 :: 2 :: 3 :: nil) = 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: nil
```

Coq destructured the instance to get `fmap0` and then applied the resulting anonymous function with the args `nat nat (fun x : nat => x + 1) (1 :: 2 :: 3 :: nil)`.

As the next step in my proof, I would like to unfold `fmap0` or the anonymous function.

How can I do this?  I cannot do `unfold fmap0`.

My expectation was that `fmap0` is the standard lib `map` because that is what I gave to the instance.

I was able to destruct the instance myself, but this shows the abstract version of `fmap0` and not the implementation that was given when instantiating the type class.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `f` is an anonymous function (that is, something of the form `fun x => expr`), then `simpl` should be enough. If it is an identifier and you cannot unfold it, then either (1) it is a local variable bound in your context, or (2) it is a global definition defined via `Qed`. In the latter case, just remove the `Qed` from your definition, replacing it by `Defined`. In the former case, I would guess that you should have tried to unfold or simplify `expr1` so that Coq can have access to the actual definition of `f` (this, in turn, might require removing `Qed`s from other global definitions).

Comment: More details after trying some stuff: `expr1` is actually an instance of a type class.  I'm not sure if this counts as an "expression". `f` is one of the methods defined in the type class. I was able to destruct the instance, but this shows the abstract version of f and not the implementation that was given when instantiating the type class, so I still can't unfold it.

Comment: @mushroom How have you defined this typeclass instance? Did you use `Qed` anywhere?

Comment: It turns out that after changing the `Qed`s to `Defined`, I can use `simpl` as suggested by Vinz below.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why, but if you simplify directly the goal

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
fmap (λ x : nat, (x + 1)%nat) (1 :: 2 :: 3 :: [ ]) = 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: [ ]
```

using `simpl` or `cbv` for example, you get your instance of `map` (in fact you get the result of `map S` applied to `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: []` hence the goal becomes trivial). I don't know why unfolding `fmap` or destructing the `ListFunctor` yields a generic `fmap0`.

Comment: This worked.  I had not tried `simpl` again after changing `Qed` to `Defined`.